# Image shuffling puzzle creation[Modified Question]

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have 3 images E1,E2,E3 of equal size 256*256*3. Now by some any arbitrary rule, i want to create a jig saw puzzle which should be a reversible operation. The resultant image E would then be of unequal size,preferably. The question is explained with a small example to show the objective for simplicity:
How to tackle the unequal sized of the resultant matrix E(image format) and how to achieve this? Please help
Example : 
size(E1)=size(E2)=3*3

```
E1=( 1 2 3
     4 5 6
     7 8 9 )

E2 = ( a b c
       d e f
       g h i)

E = ( 1 2 3  a b c
      4 5 6  d e f
      7 8 9  g h i)
```

[r c]=size(E);
But the scheme for arrangement should be such that r/c = number of matrices involved in the operation. This however would apply for even dimensioned matrix.

So, the same operation is desired for RGB image.
Modified Question : In the above case, if `E=[E1;E2]` then how is it possible to extract/get back E1 and E2 from E?

Comment: So all the pieces of your jigsaw puzzle are rectangular?

Comment: @Jacob : The original ones are square but the resulted one encapsulated all the 3 images so its size grows/increases. I am sorry I dont know which ones you are referring as rectangular.

Comment: @gavishna: Can you make an example with three arrays of size 3x3, please? I have hard time understanding your question.

Comment: Can you make the jigsaw analogy clearer? Do you consider a single 'piece' to be a matrix, or a matrix element? When you say 'reversible', what exactly do you mean? A more detailed example would help.

Comment: @Itamar Katz: reversible means that , I should be able to get back E1 and E2 from E. The entire matrix E1 and E2 are considered, but the elements are  picked up in a particular fashion, may be first three rows of E1 become the last column in the result etc. Or maybe entire E1 is put in E followed by E2 something like this E= ( E1 E2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not understand what you are doing, but you can accomplish what you have in the example easily using `reshape`:

```
E1_reshaped = reshape(e1, 1, []);
E2_reshaped = reshape(e2, 1, []);

E = [E1_reshaped; E2_reshaped];
```

Comment: @eykanal:Is it possible to include the entire matrix e1 and e2 inside the resultant E such that E is composed of e1 and e2. Further, will it be possible to extract E1_reshaped and E2_reshaped from E such that I get back the original matrix i.e to make the process reversible.

Comment: @gavishna This *will* include both the e1 and the e2 matrices (I fixed a typo, maybe that was causing your problem). You can also definitely find the original matrices. I suggest reading some of the matlab help files to learn how to work with matrices, as your problems are pretty basic.

Comment: Thank you. However, I will be relieved to know how this is reversible operation as because the pixels will be lost unless we save it in some other matrix. Further, can bitslice do the same task?

Comment: @gavishna I'm not familiar with the bitslice function, so I can't help you there... sorry!

Comment: @eykanal: Ok, no issue with that, but what about the other question, regarding the reversibility of the operation. Kindly see the modified Question for further details.

Comment: @gavishna - :) That was what I was referring to when I said "read the matlab help". You can do that doing `E1 = E(1,:)` and then using the `reshape` function, but this is very basic matlab matrix manipulation. You should definitely familiarize yourself with basic matlab syntax before proceeding. I suggest starting with the Matlab help files, which are also [available online](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/learn_matlab/f2-8955.html).